# Django queryset filter by 6 hour interval

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model

```
class TestRequest(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What i want is to send an email to admin if the TestRequest is not accepted in every 6 hours once request created.

How can i query the data in the cron function (which is running every minute) where i can fetch all the TestRequest which fall in the 6 hour interval and email to admin.

Comment: So you want to retrieve all `TestRequest`s that are at least 6 hours "old" with `is_accepted` set to `False`?

Comment: no, i want to fetch all the records which falls in 6 hours multiple like 6, 12, 18 etc from current time